# Search for list item by multi-line comment and show the item in the results not just the whole list

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, search, item

I am completely new to Microsoft SharePoint and I can not get around a problem that i guess should have a pretty simple solution.
I am working in SP 2016 without SP Designer and the problem should be solved with out of the box features, so no coding or third party solutions.

Now to the Problem:
In the company i am working (as an intern), a lot of individual problems occur during production processes. After fixing the problems, the gathered Know-How to such problems is usually lost.

My task is to create a searchable knowledge-base (a bit google-like), which can be easily and steadily extended, so if a problem occurs in the future, one can just type in a few keywords to get an entry with the information to how it was fixed in the past.

My first idea was to create a simple list, where an item can be added for every solved problem. It would contain a column (multi line comment) for the problem description as well as one for the solution.

My problem is that a "search this site" search will only return the link to the whole list or view in which the list-item is, but not a link to the item itself.
It will return the item if an attachment is added which contains the keywords or if the Title of the item contains the words, but those solutions are not what i am looking for.

Is it possible to get the item via "search this site" by multi line comments at all, or is there a better approach for my database all together?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is fundamental to SharePoint and can be done out of the box. You are new to SharePoint, so you have several separate skills to learn, but everything you are asking for is possible without code. Here is how I solve this request.

1. Create a content type and call it "KB" or "KnowledgeBaseItem".
2. Add Site Columns to the content type to define the associated data (including your multi line text field). I would also add additional fields to track the system, the technology, the knowledge expert, etc.
3. Create a custom list using your custom content type to hold your knowledge.
4. Build out the search solution in a search site with Managed Properties, Refiners and Display Templates.
5. (Optionally) Add Query Rules

It would be great if someone would do an entire video walk through of this process, but that would be hours of writing and recording. Oh, wait, I already did [Build a Search Based Site Directory](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2017/07/11/search-based-site-directory-part-1/). Just swap your KB content type for the Site Catalog Item I use in my demo.

The main problem you might encounter is that your Farm admins don't know enough about SharePoint search to actually help you. I see this a lot. If they don't crawl your content very often you may be stuck waiting on the crawl.